# "J'ai fait le bilan carbone trois fois(...)" (line from a song) - does it have any non-obvious meaning?

Tags: paroles-de-chanson

I was looking at the song lyrics the other day and this line caught my attention (this is from "*[Comment est ta peine?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ba7TB4QXzmU)*" by Benjamin Biolay) -

(...)
**J'ai fait le bilan carbone trois fois**
Puis parlé de ta daronne sur un ton
qu'tu n'aimerais pas
Tu ne le sauras jamais car tu ne l'écoutes pas
(...)

If I understand correctly, the literal translation of that line in bold is "*I calculated my carbon footprint three times*" ... but it makes little sense to me at all. Is there possibly any other slang/colloquial meaning of "*faire le bilan carbone*" that I am unaware of?

Thanks! Merci beaucoup!

Comment: Here is something that might help a little,: https://greatsong.net/paroles-comment-est-ta-peine-benjamin-biolay; in particular you should get at  the true lyrics (Paroles certifiées par nos experts).  Unfortunately, the explanation stops right before "j'ai fait le bilan…".

Comment: I wouldn't overthink it, it's probably mainly here for the rhyme - although the author might lend it another meaning but "tu ne le sauras jamais"... ;)

Answer (score 3):

J'ai trouvé cette explication sur [genius](https://genius.com/22926444) que je trouve pertinente :

> Benjamin Biolay s'amuse, dans la transcription de la conversation avec sa compagne, à juxtaposer deux sujets [...] sans rapport (afin de produire un effet de style et plus particulièrement de surprise auprès de l'auditeur). Cette hypothèse est renforcée par la suite du couplet, il peut dire n'importe quoi, « Tu ne le sauras jamais car tu ne m'écoutes pas » et sa relation est donc superficielle.

Comment: Since i dont know the language, but i realy love the song and play it over and over for months...since have read the translation on the text but please explain me the context of the song...
this is one of the best songs that i heard...on the level of Sting...